# How do you hide the camera controls within a UIImagePickerView in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIImagePickerView in my iPhone app, and would like to hide the camera controls. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a `showsCameraControls` property that you can disable:

```
myImagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
```